# Updating Files on Apache

Tags: apache

I'm having trouble with my Apache Web Server.  I have a folder (htdocs\images) where I have a number of images already in place.  I can browse them and see them on my web server (and access them via HTML).  I added a new image in there today, and went to browse to it, and it can't be found.  I double and triple checked the path and everything.  I even restarted Apache and that didn't seem to help.

I'm really confused as to what's going on here.  Anybody have any suggestions?

Thank you.

**Edit** I just turned on the ability for the images directory to be listed, browsed to it (http://127.0.0.1/images/) and I was able to see all the previous images that were in the folder, but not the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn directory indexes on for htdocs\images, remove (or move out of the way) any index.* files, and point your browser at http://yoursite/images/

That should give you a full listing of files in that directory. If the file you're looking for isn't there, then Apache is looking at a different directory than you think it is. You'll have to search your httpd.conf for clues -- DocumentRoot, Alias, AliasMatch, Redirect, RedirectMatch, RewriteRule -- there are probably dozens of apache directives that could be causing the web server to get its documents from somewhere other than where you think it's looking.

Comment: This was pretty much the problem.  I delved back into httpd.conf and found someone had set an alias to point to a different location.  How confusing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make sure the caSE and spelling are 100% correct.

Comment: Space characters in the filename might also mess with Apache

Answer (score 0):

There is not magic in programming (some may disagree:), so look for silly errors. Wrong server? Case of your letters? Wrong extension?

Comment: That's what's making me so crazy.  I go from this (in HTML):

images\picture1.png

to this

images\picture2.png

picture1 shows, picture2 does not.  Nothing else different other than I just dropped picture2.png into the images folder.

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance it could be due to the cookies stored on your device. I would delete all cookies to the website you're working on before you refresh again